# What is wrong with my script ...date range script

Tags: ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $DATE
date1='20120601'
date2='20120614'

u1=`echo $date1|cut -c1-4|tr -d ' '``echo $date1|cut -c5-6|tr -d ' '``echo $date1|cut -c7-8|tr -d ' '`

u2=`echo $date2|cut -c1-4|tr -d ' '``echo $date2|cut -c5-6|tr -d ' '``echo $date2|cut -c7-8|tr -d ' '`

echo " --- " $u1    $u2   $u3
fmt=''
while [[u1 < u2]];
do
printf '%s%(%Y%m%d)T' '$fmt' '#$u1'
[[u1+=3600*24]];
fmt=", ";
done;enter code here
printf'\n';
```

Above code doesnt work, it is not providing date range post execution. I am using AIX7.1. Please help to know what is wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance.
Sandesh

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve but the following code should at least execute without errors:

```
#!/bin/ksh
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
echo $DATE
date1='20120601'
date2='20120614'

u1=`echo $date1|cut -c1-4|tr -d ' '``echo $date1|cut -c5-6|tr -d ' '``echo $date1|cut -c7-8|tr -d ' '`

u2=`echo $date2|cut -c1-4|tr -d ' '``echo $date2|cut -c5-6|tr -d ' '``echo $date2|cut -c7-8|tr -d ' '`

echo " --- " $u1 $u2 $u3
fmt=''
while [ $u1 -lt $u2 ]
do
  printf '%s%d' "$fmt" $u1
  u1=$(( u1 + 1 ))
  fmt=", ";
done
echo
echo enter code here
printf '\n'
```

Comment: Hi, i am new to UNIX. Issue is my while loop is not working here. Here i am trying to print date range between two input date variables. Getting error as " syntax error near unexpected token `done'". Please suggest.

Comment: Getting error as :                                              bkdt1.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'kdt1.sh: line 16: `  (( u1 = u1 + 1 ))